# why the contributor option is missing any contributor profile?

Tags: github

I work in a Github repository where we work with 3 contributors but the contributor option is missing a contributor profile. Why this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Commits must be made with an email address that is connected to your account on GitHub.com, or the GitHub-provided noreply email address provided to you in your email settings, in order to appear on your contributions graph. For more information about noreply email addresses, see "Setting your commit email address

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.